Enforcing Order in a Linear Programming Question
I have an optimization model to fulfill the water requirements of a city's distribution network. The model includes water sources from rainfall collection, river extraction, reservoir storage, and external supply. I need the model to prioritize the order of water sources to meet the demand: first from rainfall collection, then from river extraction, then from reservoir storage, and finally from external supply.
We have modeled it as such: I am trying to solve a problem in which I have $4$ variables:

$x^1$: rainfall collection,
$x^2$: river extraction,
$x^3_t$: reservoir storage drained, and
$x^4_t$: external supply

($x^1$ and $x^2$ can only be chosen once across all timestamps).
I need $x^1 + x^2 + x^3_t + x^4_t \geq demand_t$, where $t$ is the current timestamp. We also have $x^3_t \leq 100$.
I basically want to encode: if ($x^1 + x^2 + x^3_t \geq demand_t$), then ($x^4_t = 0$).
How can I enforce that I drain the reservoir storage as much as possible, and only once its drained, do I use the external supply if there's any remaining demand?
We tried an attempt at $BigM$, but we were quite confused how to make it work for this problem.

Welcome to OR.SE. For the conditional statement, you can take a look at this post. Also, if you want to force the model to use more from a specific resource, one possible way would be to assign an appropriate weight to the resource into the objective function and let the model decide which one would be selected.

Also, would you elaborate more on How can I enforce that I drain the reservoir storage as much as possible, and only once its drained, do I use the external supply if there's any remaining demand?

Two questions: Why is the demand constraint $\ge$ rather than $=$ (i.e., why would you want to use more water than you need) and (regarding the lack of a time subscript on the first two variables) aren't you saying that the same water from the first two sources used in period 1 can be used again in period 2 (some sort of recycling)?

Actually, one more question: is there some reason that, absent additional constraints, the solver would want to use an external supply before the other alternatives were fully exploited? Is the external supply cheaper than some of the others?

@A.Omidi So basically it's possible that the external supply may be cheaper than the reservoir storage per gallon of water, so my model may want to use the external supply. However, I only should be able to use the external supply once the reservoir storage is fully used.

@prubin Good suggestion! We will set demand to =. Regarding the time subscript on the first two variables, yes, I am saying that the first two sources used in period 1 can be used again. And yes, without additional constraints, the external supply may be cheaper than the reservoir storage demand, so I'm trying to figure out how to constrain such that it will only use the external supply once the reservoir storage is fully used.

@snek, if you would want to use the external supply if the reservoir storage is fully used you would need to define an UB on the reservoir storage and imply $(x^3_t = UB) \implies (x^4_t \geq 0)$.

@A.Omidi I think you need to reverse the implication: $x_t^4 > 0 \implies x_t^3 = UB.$

Dear @prubin, my understanding from the mentioned comment was that the external resource can only be used when the reservoir storage is being filled. I am still waiting to get a response from OP. Also, I think it may be of the form ($\iff$) that implies what you proposed in the comment.

@A.Omidi the external supply can only be used once the reservoir storage is fully depleted

@snek, I assume you mean by depleted is equivalent to $x^3_t =0$. Now, the situation is the same and you would want to imply $(x^3_t = 0) \implies (x^4_t \gt 0)$.

For simplicity, I will omit the $t$ index.  You want to enforce $$x_1+x_2+x_3\ge d \implies x_4=0.$$
Equivalently, enforce the contrapositive
$$x_4>0 \implies x_1+x_2+x_3< d.$$
Let $\epsilon$ be a small positive constant tolerance and enforce
$$x_4>0 \implies x_1+x_2+x_3\le d-\epsilon.$$
Introduce binary decision variable $y$ and enforce
\begin{align}
x_4>0 &\implies y=1\\
y=1 &\implies x_1+x_2+x_3\le d-\epsilon
\end{align}
Rewrite as indicator constraints:
\begin{align}
y=0 &\implies x_4\le 0\\
y=1 &\implies x_1+x_2+x_3\le d-\epsilon
\end{align}
If your solver doesn’t support indicator constraints, you can linearize via big-M by imposing
\begin{align}
x_4 &\le M_1 y\\
x_1+x_2+x_3&\le d-\epsilon+M_2(1-y)
\end{align}

Similarly, to enforce the more common rule $z_1>0 \implies z_2=U_2$, where $0\le z_i\le U_i$, introduce binary decision variable $y$ and impose
\begin{align}
y=0 &\implies z_1\le 0 \\
y=1 &\implies z_2\ge U_2
\end{align}
Linearize via big-M as
\begin{align}
z_1&\le U_1 y \\
z_2&\ge U_2 y
\end{align}
